# Linear regression gives worse results after normalization or standardization

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I'm performing linear regression on this dataset:
archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/online+news+popularity

It contains various types of features - rates, binary, numbers etc.

I've tried using scikit-learn Normalizer, StandardScaler and PowerTransformer, but the've all resulted in worse results than without using them.

I'm using them like this:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
X = df.drop(columns=['url', 'shares'])
Y = df['shares']
transformer = StandardScaler().fit(X)
X_scaled = transformer.transform(X)
X_scaled = pd.DataFrame(X_scaled, columns=X.columns)
perform_linear_and_ridge_regression(X=X_scaled, Y=Y)
```

The function on the last line `perform_linear_and_ridge_regression()` is correct for sure and is using GridSearchCV to determine the best hyperparameters.

Just to make sure I include the function as well:

```
def perform_linear_and_ridge_regression(X, Y):
    X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.25, random_state=10) 
    lin_reg_parameters = { 'fit_intercept': [True, False] }
    lin_reg = GridSearchCV(LinearRegression(), lin_reg_parameters, cv=5)
    lin_reg.fit(X=X_train, y=Y_train)
    Y_pred = lin_reg.predict(X_test)
    print('Linear regression MAE =', median_absolute_error(Y_test, Y_pred))
```

The results are surprising as all of them provide worse results:

Linear reg. on original data: MAE = 1620.510555135375

Linear reg. after using Normalizer: MAE = 1979.8525218964242

Linear reg. after using StandardScaler: MAE = 2915.024521207241

Linear reg. after using PowerScaler: MAE = 1663.7148884463259

Is this just a special case, where Standardization doesn't help, or am I doing something wrong?

EDIT: Even when I leave the binary features out, most of the transformers gives worse results.

Comment: I observed exactly the same problem. I'm sure that my data is categorical as well.

Answer (score 1):

Your dataset has many categorical and ordinal features. You should take care of that first **separately**. Also, it seems like you are applying normalization on categorical variables too, which is completely wrong.

Here is [nice-link](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2015/11/easy-methods-deal-categorical-variables-predictive-modeling/), which explains how to handle categorical features for regression problem.

Comment: Which features are categorical except the url, that I have excluded from the X dataset?

Comment: Categorical data aside, consider standardizing binary values. You get non-binary values, like 0.42, which doesn't make sense.

Comment: There you can check ( https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/157053_f1c97373ae8e4240b9686d2bc6bbc08c.html), type of each feature. There are more than 20 features, which need to be transformed.

Comment: I've kept the binary values the way they are, but still got worse results.

Comment: This is multi-class problem, try using mult-class option in ligistic-regression (https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html). Little advice, please explore the data-set first, before apply any model. Because data understanding help you to fit good model.